# how to resolve could not find `__private` in `frame_support?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet

I am following following tutorial to write collectibles pallet:
https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/collectibles-workshop/.

My source code is available here:
https://github.com/sayyedkamran/substrate-node-template

The collectible pallet compiled successfully. When I try to add it to the runtime it is giving some very strange errors:

```sh
syedkamran@192 substrate-node-template % cargo build --release
warning: some crates are on edition 2021 which defaults to `resolver = "2"`, but virtual workspaces default to `resolver = "1"`
note: to keep the current resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "1"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: to use the edition 2021 resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "2"` in the workspace root's manifest
    Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache
   Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-dbf9bf989bdc97d4/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=mvp -C target-feature=-sign-ext -C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/Users/syedkamran/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.74.0-nightly (8550f15e1 2023-08-27)

  --- stderr
     Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime)
  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `__private` in `frame_support`
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:289:1
      |
  289 | / construct_runtime!(
  290 | |     pub struct Runtime {
  291 | |         System: frame_system,
  292 | |         Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
  ...   |
  301 | |     }
  302 | | );
      | |_^ could not find `__private` in `frame_support`
      |
      = note: this error originates in the macro `collectibles::tt_default_parts` which comes from the expansion of the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Aura` in this scope
    --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:92:14
     |
  92 |             pub aura: Aura,
     |                       ^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Grandpa` in this scope
    --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:93:17
     |
  93 |             pub grandpa: Grandpa,
     |                          ^^^^^^^ help: a type alias with a similar name exists: `GrandpaId`
     |
    ::: /Users/syedkamran/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/consensus/grandpa/src/lib.rs:57:1
     |
  57 | pub type AuthorityId = app::Public;
     | -------------------- similarly named type alias `GrandpaId` defined here

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Aura` in this scope
    --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:92:14
     |
  92 |             pub aura: Aura,
     |                       ^^^^ not found in this scope
     |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
    --> /Users/syedkamran/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:1997:19
     |
  199|         pub struct $name<Aura> {
     |                         ++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Grandpa` in this scope
    --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:93:17
     |
  93 |             pub grandpa: Grandpa,
     |                          ^^^^^^^
     |
    ::: /Users/syedkamran/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/consensus/grandpa/src/lib.rs:57:1
     |
  57 | pub type AuthorityId = app::Public;
     | -------------------- similarly named type alias `GrandpaId` defined here
     |
  help: a type alias with a similar name exists
     |
  93 |             pub grandpa: GrandpaId,
     |                          ~~~~~~~~~
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
    --> /Users/syedkamran/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:1997:19
     |
  199|         pub struct $name<Grandpa> {
     |                         +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Aura` in this scope
    --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:92:14
     |
  92 |             pub aura: Aura,
     |                       ^^^^ not found in this scope
     |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
    --> /Users/syedkamran/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:1994:32
     |
  199|             $crate::scale_info::TypeInfo<Aura>,
     |                                         ++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Grandpa` in this scope
    --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:93:17
     |
  93 |             pub grandpa: Grandpa,
     |                          ^^^^^^^
     |
    ::: /Users/syedkamran/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/consensus/grandpa/src/lib.rs:57:1
     |
  57 | pub type AuthorityId = app::Public;
     | -------------------- similarly named type alias `GrandpaId` defined here
     |
  help: a type alias with a similar name exists
     |
  93 |             pub grandpa: GrandpaId,
     |                          ~~~~~~~~~
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
    --> /Users/syedkamran/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:1994:32
     |
  199|             $crate::scale_info::TypeInfo<Grandpa>,
     |                                         +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:158:31
      |
  158 | impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
      |                               ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeCall` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:170:21
      |
  170 |     type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
      |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::RuntimeCall`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeEvent` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:180:22
      |
  180 |     type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
      |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::RuntimeEvent`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeOrigin` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:182:23
      |
  182 |     type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
      |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::RuntimeOrigin`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `PalletInfo` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:192:20
      |
  192 |     type PalletInfo = PalletInfo;
      |                       ^^^^^^^^^^
      |
  help: you might have meant to use the associated type
      |
  192 |     type PalletInfo = Self::PalletInfo;
      |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  help: consider importing this trait
      |
  9   + use frame_support::traits::PalletInfo;
      |

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:208:30
      |
  208 | impl pallet_aura::Config for Runtime {
      |                              ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:215:33
      |
  215 | impl pallet_grandpa::Config for Runtime {
      |                                 ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeEvent` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:216:22
      |
  216 |     type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
      |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::RuntimeEvent`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:226:35
      |
  226 | impl pallet_timestamp::Config for Runtime {
      |                                   ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Aura` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:229:24
      |
  229 |     type OnTimestampSet = Aura;
      |                           ^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:237:34
      |
  237 | impl pallet_balances::Config for Runtime {
      |                                  ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeEvent` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:244:22
      |
  244 |     type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
      |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::RuntimeEvent`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `System` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:247:22
      |
  247 |     type AccountStore = System;
      |                         ^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:248:62
      |
  248 |     type WeightInfo = pallet_balances::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
      |                                                                 ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  237 | impl<Runtime> pallet_balances::Config for Runtime {
      |     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:259:45
      |
  259 | impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
      |                                             ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeEvent` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:260:22
      |
  260 |     type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
      |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::RuntimeEvent`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Balances` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:261:45
      |
  66  | pub type Balance = u128;
      | ------------------------ similarly named type alias `Balance` defined here
  ...
  261 |     type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, ()>;
      |                                                ^^^^^^^^
      |
  help: a type alias with a similar name exists
      |
  261 |     type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balance, ()>;
      |                                                ~~~~~~~
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  259 | impl<Balances> pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
      |     ++++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:268:30
      |
  268 | impl pallet_sudo::Config for Runtime {
      |                              ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeEvent` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:269:22
      |
  269 |     type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
      |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::RuntimeEvent`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeCall` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:270:21
      |
  270 |     type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
      |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::RuntimeCall`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:271:58
      |
  271 |     type WeightInfo = pallet_sudo::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
      |                                                             ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  268 | impl<Runtime> pallet_sudo::Config for Runtime {
      |     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:275:34
      |
  275 | impl pallet_template::Config for Runtime {
      |                                  ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeEvent` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:276:22
      |
  276 |     type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
      |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::RuntimeEvent`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:277:62
      |
  277 |     type WeightInfo = pallet_template::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
      |                                                                 ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  275 | impl<Runtime> pallet_template::Config for Runtime {
      |     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:281:31
      |
  281 | impl collectibles::Config for Runtime {
      |                               ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeEvent` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:282:25
      |
  282 |     type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
      |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::RuntimeEvent`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Balances` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:283:21
      |
  66  | pub type Balance = u128;
      | ------------------------ similarly named type alias `Balance` defined here
  ...
  283 |     type Currency = Balances;
      |                     ^^^^^^^^ help: a type alias with a similar name exists: `Balance`

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RandomnessCollectiveFlip` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:284:33
      |
  284 |     type CollectionRandomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
      |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:312:35
      |
  312 |     frame_system::CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>,
      |                                      ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  311 | pub type SignedExtra<Runtime> = (
      |                     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:313:33
      |
  313 |     frame_system::CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>,
      |                                    ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  311 | pub type SignedExtra<Runtime> = (
      |                     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:314:31
      |
  314 |     frame_system::CheckTxVersion<Runtime>,
      |                                  ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  311 | pub type SignedExtra<Runtime> = (
      |                     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:315:29
      |
  315 |     frame_system::CheckGenesis<Runtime>,
      |                                ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  311 | pub type SignedExtra<Runtime> = (
      |                     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:316:25
      |
  316 |     frame_system::CheckEra<Runtime>,
      |                            ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  311 | pub type SignedExtra<Runtime> = (
      |                     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:317:27
      |
  317 |     frame_system::CheckNonce<Runtime>,
      |                              ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  311 | pub type SignedExtra<Runtime> = (
      |                     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:318:28
      |
  318 |     frame_system::CheckWeight<Runtime>,
      |                               ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  311 | pub type SignedExtra<Runtime> = (
      |                     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:319:55
      |
  319 |     pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>,
      |                                                          ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  311 | pub type SignedExtra<Runtime> = (
      |                     +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeCall` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:324:39
      |
  324 |     generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, RuntimeCall, Signature, SignedExtra>;
      |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  323 | pub type UncheckedExtrinsic<RuntimeCall> =
      |                            +++++++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeCall` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:326:49
      |
  326 | pub type SignedPayload = generic::SignedPayload<RuntimeCall, SignedExtra>;
      |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  326 | pub type SignedPayload<RuntimeCall> = generic::SignedPayload<RuntimeCall, SignedExtra>;
      |                       +++++++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:329:2
      |
  329 |     Runtime,
      |     ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  328 | pub type Executive<Runtime> = frame_executive::Executive<
      |                   +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:331:29
      |
  331 |     frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
      |                                ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  328 | pub type Executive<Runtime> = frame_executive::Executive<
      |                   +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:332:2
      |
  332 |     Runtime,
      |     ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  328 | pub type Executive<Runtime> = frame_executive::Executive<
      |                   +++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `AllPalletsWithSystem` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:333:2
      |
  333 |     AllPalletsWithSystem,
      |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  328 | pub type Executive<AllPalletsWithSystem> = frame_executive::Executive<
      |                   ++++++++++++++++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:353:31
      |
  353 |     impl sp_api::Core<Block> for Runtime {
      |                                  ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:367:35
      |
  367 |     impl sp_api::Metadata<Block> for Runtime {
      |                                      ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:381:49
      |
  381 |     impl sp_block_builder::BlockBuilder<Block> for Runtime {
      |                                                    ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:402:75
      |
  402 |     impl sp_transaction_pool::runtime_api::TaggedTransactionQueue<Block> for Runtime {
      |                                                                              ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:412:49
      |
  412 |     impl sp_offchain::OffchainWorkerApi<Block> for Runtime {
      |                                                    ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:418:53
      |
  418 |     impl sp_consensus_aura::AuraApi<Block, AuraId> for Runtime {
      |                                                        ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:428:42
      |
  428 |     impl sp_session::SessionKeys<Block> for Runtime {
      |                                             ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:440:51
      |
  440 |     impl sp_consensus_grandpa::GrandpaApi<Block> for Runtime {
      |                                                      ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:470:82
      |
  470 |     impl frame_system_rpc_runtime_api::AccountNonceApi<Block, AccountId, Nonce> for Runtime {
      |                                                                                     ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:476:93
      |
  476 |     impl pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::TransactionPaymentApi<Block, Balance> for Runtime {
      |                                                                                                ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeCall` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:497:93
      |
  497 |     impl pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::TransactionPaymentCallApi<Block, Balance, RuntimeCall>
      |                                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
      |
  help: you might be missing a type parameter
      |
  497 |     impl<RuntimeCall> pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::TransactionPaymentCallApi<Block, Balance, RuntimeCall>
      |         +++++++++++++

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `Runtime` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:498:7
      |
  498 |         for Runtime
      |             ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeCall` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:501:10
      |
  501 |             call: RuntimeCall,
      |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeCall` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:507:10
      |
  507 |             call: RuntimeCall,
      |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `RuntimeCall` in this scope
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:497:93
      |
  497 |     impl pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::TransactionPaymentCallApi<Block, Balance, RuntimeCall>
      |                                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

  error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-3d99c77e35d60298.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-2276528edc6133c9.rmeta

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Runtime`
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:369:24
      |
  369 |             OpaqueMetadata::new(Runtime::metadata().into())
      |                                 ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `Runtime`

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Runtime`
     --> /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-
```

Comment: `__private` module doesn't export any items.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the main error. The macro is unable to generate code correctly, resulting in multiple errors.

Based on my observation:

```rs
error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-3d99c77e35d60298.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/syedkamran/polkadot/kamran/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-2276528edc6133c9.rmeta
```

I believe you may have missed some `"xxx/std"` entries in your `Cargo.toml`, or you are using different versions of dependencies. Please check your `Cargo.lock`; generally, there should only be one Substrate version.

Comment: You seems to be right. The issue is, everything gets compiled correctly, as soon as I add collectibles pallet to the runtime, these strange errors pops in. I observer following strange thing in the cargo.lock file

[[package]]
name = "frame-system"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
source = "git+https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2fd1233dc26dbb9f9bbc1d2cca2c03945d"
[[package]]
name = "frame-system"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
source = "git+https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git?branch=release-polkadot-v1.1.0#f60318f68687e601c47de5ad5ca88e2c3f8139a7"
d